# Hide element when focus lost

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, show-hide

I'm working on drop down menu with css and jquery. I wish to be menu open until I click something or until I click out of the menu.

This is what I have tried:

```
$('#optionButton').click(function() {
$('#dropMenu').css('visibility' , 'visible')    //optionButton clicked, menu visible
});

$('*').not('#optionButton').click(function() {
$('#dropMenu').css('visibility' , 'hidden') //clicked eanithing else: menu close
});
```

But it doesn't work how I expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("body").click(function(e) {
    if ( e.target.id === "optionButton" ) {
        $("#dropMenu").css("visibility", "visible");
    }
    else {
        $("#dropMenu").css("visibility", "hidden");
    }
});
```

Or, the shorter version of the same thing:

```
$("body").click(function(e) {
    $("#dropMenu").css("visibility", ( e.target.id === "optionButton" ? "visible" : "hidden" ));
});
```

Answer (score 4):

When you click on an DOM object, it does event bubbling, which means it starts from the most specific object and bubbles up the DOM tree until it gets to the `document` object. You can prevent an event from bubbling up the DOM treee by returning `false`.

```
$(document).click(function() {
  $('#dropMenu').hide();
});

$('#optionButton').click(function() { 
  $('#dropMenu').show();
  return false;
});
```

Notice how I used the `hide` and `show` methods instead of `css('visibility' , 'visible/hidden')`. These two actually [do slightly different things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone), nut if you just wanted to hide an element, the `hide` method is the easiest way to do it in jQuery.

You can see a [working example of this on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZuLHb/).

Answer (score 3):

I did the experiment with CSS only. May be it's work for your.

Check http://jsfiddle.net/ZuLHb/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can bind a click event on the document to closez the mùeny:

```
$(document).click(function() {
    $('#dropMenu').css('visibility' , 'hidden') //clicked eanithing else: menu close
});
```

The important part is that you stop event propagation on the click event of the `#optionButton`, otherwise the event will bubble up to the document and execute the click handler attached to it:

```
$('#optionButton').click(function(e) {
    $('#dropMenu').css('visibility' , 'visible')    //optionButton clicked, menu visible
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/rvXFT/)**

Comment: One would need a `return false` for the `$('#optionButton').click` though.

Comment: Stopping propagation is actually what is needed.